# Can't get user post_count in WordPress using get_the_author_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having troubles with getting a post count (total) for users.
I think it has to do the **get_the_author_posts**, which should give me the users total post - expressed as a number.

```
function all_authors_list() {
    $authors = get_users(array(
        'role'      => 'subscriber',
        'orderby'   => 'post_count',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'number'    => '20',
        )
    );

    foreach($authors as $author) {
        echo '<li class="author-name">' . $author->first_name . ' ' . $author->last_name . '</li>';
        echo '<div class="author-post-count">' . $author->get_the_author_posts() . '</div>';
    }
}
```

All of this works, except the author post count line.
Any ideas?

(thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What goes wrong? Is it "0"? Do you get an error?

Comment: It just doesn't echo out - the post count part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count_user_posts()` to get the post count for a user.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts

In your case:

```
function all_authors_list() {
    $authors = get_users(array(
        'role'      => 'subscriber',
        'orderby'   => 'post_count',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'number'    => '20',
        )
    );

    foreach($authors as $author) {
        echo '<li class="author-name">' . $author->first_name . ' ' . $author->last_name . '</li>';
        echo '<div class="author-post-count">' . count_user_posts($author->ID) . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try this one :

`echo '<div class="author-post-count">' . get_the_author_posts() . '</div>';`

instead of

`echo '<div class="author-post-count">' . $author->get_the_author_posts() . '</div>';`

And you can also try this one :

`echo '<div class="author-post-count">' . count_user_posts(your_author_id) . '</div>';`

Hope this helps..